# Upload sendfile file as attachment and download the file in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to upload the file and send the uploaded file as attachment in mail and download the file from webpage. Contents of the file is stored in the database with mediumblob datatype. Uploading file and sending file as attachment works fine. When I download the file contents are not in the readable format. The contents are display as

```
PD9waHANCg0KLy8gTWFrZSBhIE15U1FMIENvbm5lY3Rpb24NCiRob3N0PSJUZWthbGFkYi5kYi45
MTM1MTgyLmhvc3RlZHJlc291cmNlLmNvbSI7DQokdXNlcj0iVGVrYWxhZGIiOw0KJHBhc3N3b3Jk
```

Here is the code

upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// Read POST request params into global vars
include_once "db.php";

$name1=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['name1']));
$subject1=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['subject1']));
$email1=$_POST['email1'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['sess_user4']);
  $to = "abc@gmail.com";
 $from=$_POST['email1'];
 $fileatt      = $_FILES['fileatt']['tmp_name'];
 $fileatt_type = $_FILES['fileatt']['type'];
 $fileatt_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileatt']['name']);
 $fileatt_size = $_FILES['fileatt']['size']; 
 $aa=filesize($fileatt);
$headers = "From: $from";
if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
  // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
$name1=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['name1']));
  $file = fopen($fileatt,'r');
  $content = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));


fclose($file);
$message="Name:$name1\n\n
          Email:$email1\n
          Subject:$subject1\n
          Phone No:$phone";
  // Generate a boundary string
  $semi_rand = md5(time());
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


  // Add the headers for a file attachment
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
              "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
              " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  // Add a multipart boundary above the plain message
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
             "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
             "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
            stripslashes($message). "\n\n";

  // Base64 encode the file data
  $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

  // Add file attachment to the message
  $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
              "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
              " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
              //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
              //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
              $content . "\n\n" .
              "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

}

// Send the message
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($ok) {
   echo "<script>window.open('display.php','_self')</script>";
} else {
  echo "<p>Mail could not be sent. Sorry!</p>";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO register (name,type,size,content,name1,email1,subject1,phone,username) VALUES ('$fileatt_name','$fileatt_type','$fileatt_size','$content','$name1','$email1','$subject1','$phone','$username')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');  

?>
```

download.php

```
   <html>
        <head>
            <title>Download File From MySQL Database</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
                  charset=iso-8859-1">
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
     include_once "db.php";
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) { // if id is set then get the file with the id from database
   $id = $_GET['id'];
 $content = chunk_split(base64_decode($content));
   $query = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM register WHERE id = $id";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
   list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   header("Content-length: $size");
   header("Content-type: $type");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
   echo $content; exit;
   }
   $query = "SELECT id, name FROM register";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
  {
   echo "Database is empty";
  }
  else
  {
   while(list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
   ?> 
     <a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
   <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is in headers, which already sets. 
Try this code:

```
<?php
include_once "db.php";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) { // if id is set then get the file with the id from database
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM register WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    echo base64_decode(str_replace("\n", "", $content));
    exit;
} else {
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Download File From MySQL Database</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM register";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "Database is empty";
}
else {
    while (list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
        <?php
    }
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If add the above code also the problem is same. Uploaded file read the contents whereas the file downloaded read the contents as follows.   UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDfpNJsWgEAACAFAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAAC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: as you have base64 encoded the file, i think the only thing that is missing here is base64 DECODE

Comment: and off course you need to revert chunk_split ;) by removing new lines

Comment: If i use base64 decode in download.php it is the same thing File is read in the same format. I have edit the code above. I have used it in this way. $content = chunk_split(base64_decode($content));

Comment: try to use code aboce replacing ````echo $content;```` with ````echo base64_decode(str_replace("\n", "", $content));````